# Server side URL redirect

Tags: http, web, weblogic

I have a long URL that points to initial page of the website and I want to make it simple so user can remember it. I don't want to do client-side redirects, I want to do it on server side to make it faster. 
I use Weblogic as a web-server.

Is there a way to redirect from say http://aaa.com/subproject to
http://aaa.com/Project/subproject/index.html? What files should I modify achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you only want to do this for the first url?

If only the first, just create an entry in `web.xml` pointing the `<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>` to some `index.jsp` in the root for the webapp named `subproject`.

In this index.jsp, do a `jsp:forward` to the actual url you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I actually moved the first page to the root since I didn't get the answer in some time, but I think your method would have worked.